# Shorten some names of my column values in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a list of species, however, in some cases, my species names are short (e.g, "Ajuga reptans") but sometimes I have subsp names (such as "Agrostis capillaris vinealis" or also "Allium senescens ssp montanum"). I am looking for a way to shorten the names of all my species, to switch from:

```
   species
1  Ajuga reptans
2  Agrostis capillaris vinealis
3  Allium senescens ssp  montanum
```

to

```
   species
1  Ajuga reptans
2  Agrostis capillaris 
3  Allium senescens
```

So, delete the end names of my species, only if my "species names" are greater than two words.

Any suggestions? I tried to use `gsub` but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sub('(\\w+ \\w+).*', '\\1', df$species)
```

Using the above, you could then do:

```
df$spec2 <- sub('(\\w+ \\w+).*', '\\1', df$species)
df
                         species               spec2
1                  Ajuga reptans       Ajuga reptans
2   Agrostis capillaris vinealis Agrostis capillaris
3 Allium senescens ssp  montanum    Allium senescens
>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use  `stringr::word` -

```
df$species <- stringr::word(df$species, 1, 2)
df

#              species
#1       Ajuga reptans
#2 Agrostis capillaris
#3    Allium senescens
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be

```
sapply(df$species, 
       function(i) paste(unlist(strsplit(i, " "))[1:2], collapse = " ")) -> df$species2
```

which will yield the following:

```
#                          species            species2
# 1                  Ajuga reptans       Ajuga reptans
# 2   Agrostis capillaris vinealis Agrostis capillaris
# 3 Allium senescens ssp  montanum    Allium senescens
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `abbreviate()` function in base R. That's what it's designed to do.